# Query by specific event_params.key

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase analytics and have my event params in google big query. I did this query:

`SELECT * FROM 'myProject.analytics_number.events_2021*', UNNEST(event_params) AS param WHERE event_name ="Read_Free_Article" AND param.value.string_value="X"`

this gives me results like this:
[image]

Now I'd like to query multiple things. For example I'd like to query `avg(timeSpend)` to get the average timeSpend value and `count(title) ... group by title` to get the count of events that have the same title value.

But I don't understand how I can query by the different event_params.key values. I only managed to query by the `event_name` and `param.value.string_value` which just checks if **any** event_params.value.string_value has the desired value.

Comment: request you to add a sample data and expected o/p. this is doable.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the individual param values in the select part of the query like this:

```
    SELECT (SELECT ep.value.string_value)
            FROM UNNEST(event_params) ep
            WHERE ep.key = 'title') title,
           (SELECT ep.value.string_value
            FROM UNNEST(event_params) ep
            WHERE ep.key = 'publisher') publisher,
            COUNT(1) count_titles,
           (SELECT AVG(CAST(ep.value.string_value AS numeric))
            FROM UNNEST(event_params) ep
            WHERE ep.key = 'timeSpend) avg_time_spend,
    FROM `myProject.analytics_number.events_2021*`
    WHERE event_name ='Read_Free_Article'
    AND publisher = 'X'
    GROUP BY 
       title,
       publisher
```